# Can an enamelled pan be changed from meat to milk/pareve?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, meat, dairy, kashering-kosherization

I have a metal pan that is enameled white on the inside, which I have had for more than 40 years, and hardly used. I originally intended it for meat, but now I think I might get some use out of it if it were milk/pareve. I have not used it at all in years. Can I do this? If so, how do I kosher it for milk?

Comment: Hello Carol, and welcome to Mi Yodeya! Please keep in mind that Mi Yodeya is not really a place for practical halachic advice -- any information you get here should be [treated as if it came from a crowd of your friends](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) ....that said, I hope you stay around to enjoy the site!

Comment: This question is about enamel metal pots. So it should be reopenend.

Comment: @GershonGold If enamel makes a difference, that should be clearly explained in the question itself. As it stands, it's still a duplicate.