# Kashering enamel-ware

Tags: halacha, kashering-kosherization

How does one kasher enamelware like [Le Creuset](http://www.lecreuset.com) (if it is at all possible)?

Note: enamelware cooking implements are typically cast-iron with a glazed enamel covering most of the of the surface, except for the base, which contacts the burner. The enamel is smooth and can withstand high temperatures (but not direct heat); furthermore, it changes the thermal properties of the implement, making it particularly good for use in slow cooking (think brisket).

Comment: Related: Seth J's questions on kashering processes

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44969/can-an-enamelled-pan-be-changed-from-meat-to-milk-pareve

Comment: Enamel porcelain sinks cannot be kashered. I would assume this would be the same for enamelware.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is, if you follow Ashkenazi Orthodox halachah, you can't kasher enameled cookware, because you can't kasher glass.  Ashkenazi law holds that glass is earthenware, and absorbs non-kosher "flavor".  Sephardic law does not agree, and states that glass does not absorb, and therefore can be kashered the normal ways (boiling or very high heat for something that touches fire in use).

Comment: Pleased add your sources and show how they fit the question.

Comment: The Ashkenazi custom is just the opposite - it’s not that glass *can’t* be kashered but that it doesn’t *need* to be kashered, as it doesn’t absorb. For the record, materials besides for earthenware absorb.

Comment: Here is a page from the CRC which says the custom is not to kasher porcelain: http://www.crcweb.org/kosher_articles/Kashering_in_the_Kitchen.php